# symfony6 install KnpMenuBundle

Tags: symfony6, knpmenubundle

I want to install `KnpMenuBundle` into an empty Symfony project (--webapp project).

I make steps from [KnpMenuBundle documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/current/index.html) but it does not work.

configuration

- symfony 6.1.7
- KnpMenuBundle downloaded: 3.2

Here are my different files:

composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.13",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^3.2",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.13",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/asset": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.1",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.1.*"
    }
}
```

config.bundles.php

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

config/packages/knp_menu.yaml

```
# config/packages/knp_menu.yaml
knp_menu:
    # use "twig: false" to disable the Twig extension and the TwigRenderer
    twig:
        template: KnpMenuBundle::menu.html.twig
    #  if true, enables the helper for PHP templates
    templating: false
    # the renderer to use, list is also available by default
    default_renderer: twig
```

src/Menu/Builder.php

```
<?php

// src/Menu/Builder.php
namespace App\Menu;

use App\Entity\Blog;
use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

final class Builder implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options): ItemInterface
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Home', ['route' => 'homepage']);

        // access services from the container!
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        // findMostRecent and Blog are just imaginary examples
        $blog = $em->getRepository(Blog::class)->findMostRecent();

        $menu->addChild('Latest Blog Post', [
            'route' => 'blog_show',
            'routeParameters' => ['id' => $blog->getId()]
        ]);

        // create another menu item
        $menu->addChild('About Me', ['route' => 'about']);
        // you can also add sub levels to your menus as follows
        $menu['About Me']->addChild('Edit profile', ['route' => 'edit_profile']);

        // ... add more children

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

src/Controller/IndexController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_index')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'IndexController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

templates/index/index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello IndexController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<style>
    .example-wrapper { margin: 1em auto; max-width: 800px; width: 95%; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
    .example-wrapper code { background: #F5F5F5; padding: 2px 6px; }
</style>

<div class="example-wrapper">
    <h1>Hello {{ controller_name }}! ✅</h1>

    This friendly message is coming from:
    <ul>
        <li>Your controller at <code><a href="{{ '/media/sambano/home_HDD_EXTERNE/Documents/php/projets_eclipse/php_symfony_projet03_test05/src/Controller/IndexController.php'|file_link(0) }}">src/Controller/IndexController.php</a></code></li>
        <li>Your template at <code><a href="{{ '/media/sambano/home_HDD_EXTERNE/Documents/php/projets_eclipse/php_symfony_projet03_test05/templates/index/index.html.twig'|file_link(0) }}">templates/index/index.html.twig</a></code></li>
    </ul>
</div>

{{ knp_menu_render('App:Builder:mainMenu') }}
{% endblock %}
```

NOTES:

- when I install `KnpMenuBundle`, `config/packages/knp_menu.yaml` did not exist, I had to create it and paste inside the code.
- `src/Menu` folder did not exist, I had to create it with `Builder.php` inside and paste the code.
- when I added `{{ knp_menu_render('App:Builder:mainMenu') }}` into my `templates/index/index.html.twig`, I got the error:

  ```
  An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
  ("Bundle "App" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you 
  forgot to add it in the "registerBundles()" method of your 
  "App\Kernel.php" file?").
  ```

If you have any ideas, clues, or anything else, I'm listening because I don't know where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

I am using method b: a menu builder as a service without any problems.

Look at the [documentation page](https://symfony.com/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/current/menu_builder_service.html). So I recommend you do the same way.

Comment: hi, the b) method was a success. i Only wanted to succed the A) method in order to be ale to choose my workflow. Not a problem for the moment i will make new attempts in a while. Thks anyway.